# Why are we receiving notifications about flags in other chat room?

Tags: support, chat

In the past few days, while visiting our chat room, I've received two notifications about spam/offensive flags in other chat rooms: I am attaching a screen capture of one such notification:

[image: Example of notification about spam/offensive flags in other chat rooms]

Apparently some other members have received similar notifications. Why is this happening? Is it a new feature or a bug? If it is a feature, it is one I definitively don't want and I would like to somehow disable it (I consider those messages a little bit annoying.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This has always been the case for users with a network-wide reputation greater than 10.000. At this point you have the ability to see spam/offensive flags in chat. Those flags are global, they are not restricted to any specific room but shown to all 10k users and mods on the entire SE 2.0 chat.

If you do not wish to act on any chat flags you can safely ignore that indicator, chat flags are usually dealt with quickly and should disappear soon.

You might be interested in the following feature requests to either allow opting-out of chat flagging entirely or to not show the chat flags immediately to users in completely unrelated rooms:

- [Add escalation system to chat flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112756/add-escalation-system-to-chat-flags)
- [Opt-Out for chat flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121912/opt-out-for-chat-flags)

Comment: Yes but when you click on the blue flagged message number it says there are no flagged messages. So either it's slow or we don't need to see it.

Comment: @percusse It probably means someone already took care of them.

Answer (score 4):

We moderators get this notifications already since quite a time. Maybe high-rep users (in total rep) can now vote on them, too. It's a little confusing and a lot more annoying.

The reason is, I guess, that the chat is kind of a realm for itself and is not limited to the main sites the particular chat room you are in is linked. You have a own chat Id for example, which you got AFAIK when entering the chat the first time. Also my moderator powers seem to work in other sites chat-room as well. Recently I could unlock a Skeptics.SE chat room without any issue.

Comment: Yes, you're a moderator in any chat of any site. It's separated from the actual site you moderate. :)